# Debugging native code in android under eclipse fails

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk, ubuntu-12.10, csip-simple

I'm trying to debug the native code in the "csipsimple" android app using the `Debug As->Android Native Application` option. I used [this](http://tools.android.com/recent/usingthendkplugin) tutorial to do it. I keep getting these errors:

```
[2013-06-09 17:24:24 - SipHome] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2013-06-09 17:24:24 - SipHome] Android
[2013-06-09 17:24:24 - SipHome] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2013-06-09 17:24:24 - SipHome] NDK:
[2013-06-09 17:24:24 - SipHome] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2013-06-09 17:24:24 - SipHome] Uses
[2013-06-09 17:24:24 - SipHome] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2013-06-09 17:24:24 - SipHome] local
[2013-06-09 17:24:24 - SipHome] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2013-06-09 17:24:24 - SipHome] settings
[2013-06-09 17:24:24 - SipHome] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2013-06-09 17:24:24 - SipHome] 
[2013-06-09 17:24:24 - SipHome] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2013-06-09 17:24:24 - SipHome] 
[2013-06-09 17:24:24 - SipHome] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2013-06-09 17:24:24 - SipHome] 
[2013-06-09 17:24:24 - SipHome] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2013-06-09 17:24:24 - SipHome] 
armeabi
[2013-06-09 17:24:24 - SipHome] Unable to detect application ABI's
```

I tried

[Unable to detect application ABI's when trying to debug NDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12733125/unable-to-detect-application-abis-when-trying-to-debug-ndk) (not relevant, I didn't use Sequoya),

http://www.cocos2d-x.org/boards/6/topics/24216 (didn't work)

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-ndk/icsQtRy1FZQ (worked mysteriously one time only)

http://www.mjbshaw.com/2012/11/android-ndk-eclipse-fixing-unknown.html (not the problem)

http://en.it-usenet.org/thread/12874/17301/ (didn't work)

I'm using the ADT bundle v22 (eclipse 4.2.1), with the Android NDK r8e, under Ubuntu 12.10.

csipsimple uses jni and swig to call the native code.

I'm desperate, help me!

Comment: Does Eclipse > Preferences > Android > NDK have the right path ?

Comment: We're seeing this problem as well but only after moving to NDK r9.

Answer (score 8):

For NDK R9 (works in others too but line# may differ):

```
${NDK}/build/core/add-application.mk
line 138
```

add "#" at start of the line.

```bash
# $(call __ndk_info,WARNING: APP_PLATFORM $(APP_PLATFORM) is larger than \
    android:minSdkVersion $(APP_MIN_PLATFORM_LEVEL) in $(APP_MANIFEST))
```

One character, 30 second fix ... go debug native code.

Comment: This gets the application to launch but it still can't be debugged (hit breakpoints in C++ code) it seems.                                           We get output like:                                                                         "run-as: Package 'com.our.app' is unknown
Verify if the application was built with NDK_DEBUG=1"

Comment: solution worked, but read the comment above, by eodabash.. Application does not gets debugged..

Comment: Hitting breakpoints is unrelated to the above APP_PLATFORM warning. There are any number of reasons breakpoints may not be hit. Try building manually from command line using the Android tools. For instance: 1) "ndk-build NDK_DEBUG=1"  ... 2) "ant debug" ... and 3) ndk-gdb --launch=com.your.app.activity    ...  to launch app and verify can set breakpoints. If ndk-gdb cannot debug c++ then Eclipse won't either. Also, it sometimes helps to run and debug the app as a java app first and then run it again for native debuggging.

Comment: In Eclipse ... make sure you added the NDK_DEBUG=1 option in the project's C/C++ settings for the build command.

Answer (score 2):

After getting this to work, and then re-creating my app to see what works, I have found the following:

in the AndroidManifest.xml, you have to set min/target SDK version to match that of your phone.

```
[jc@jc-u13:anotherJniDebugTest]$ adb shell getprop|grep build.version
[ro.build.version.codename]: [REL]
[ro.build.version.incremental]: [5c6c6b0b1b]
[ro.build.version.release]: [4.3.1]
**[ro.build.version.sdk]: [18]**
```

therefore, my manifest versions had to be 18.  If i had my version set to 17, i would get the above error

Answer (score 0):

Do you use the info, warn, etc. functions to log messages in any of your Android.mk files? Like `$(info my-log-message)` It looks like your do and it's logging the string:

> Android NDK: Uses local settings

If so, remove them all and try again.