# How can I fix "Unable to detect application ABI" on Windows?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk

I have exactly the same problem described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20047348/unknown-application-abi-while-debug-as-native-application). I wanted to add a comment but I don't have enough reputation (I just registered some days ago).

I have checked what `Alex Cohn` suggested:

> On Windows especially, it could be because one of the files
>   (project.properties, Application.mk, Android.mk, or
>   AndroidManfest.xml) has wrong line endings (CRLF). You run ndk-build
>   DUMP_APP_ABI and make sure the output is clean.

All those files had CRLF and I have fixed using Notepad++ (Edit/EOL conversion -> convert to UNIX format) but I stil get an extra empty line when I run ndk-build DUMP_APP_ABI. It also happens when I run it in the NDK samples folders, so it makes me think it's not a project specific issue.

I have ran **ndk-gdb --start --verbose --force** in Cygwin and it works.

> Device API Level: 19
>   Device CPU ABIs: armeabi-v7a armeabi
>   Compatible device ABI: armeabi

My platform is Windows 8.1, using Android NDK r9d and adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321. Everything is the 64 bits version. I have tried in Linux and it works OK with exactly the same project.

Any idea or suggestion?

**EDIT**

I have copied all my folders (eclipse, android sdk, android ndk and project folder) into another Windows computer and it works, I can debug. If I run `ndk-build.cmd DUMP_APP_ABI` on that computer **I also get an extra line**. Any suggestion on what could be broken on my computer?

Comment: Fixed it? Found a workaround? I am sorry I missed your Q in April.

Comment: Thanks for answering Alex, you seem to be the only one who knows about this problem! No, I haven't fixed it and my workaround is to work in a Linux virtual machine when I need to debug Native code (which is very slow). Any idea how to fix it on Windows?

Comment: You're right, my favorite answer to the question _"how to debug native Android under Windows?"_ begins with words _[format your C: drive to ext4](http://askubuntu.com/questions/331353/how-to-replace-windows-with-ubuntu)_.‌​

Comment: haha of course I would have done that, but I'm a little stuck on Windows (that's my work computer, at home Windows is only for playing games ^^).
Since I tried on other computers and worked properly, I assume that the extra line when running ndk-build.cmd DUMP_APP_ABI is not that bad. Do you have any other suggestion?