# Android NDK fails to debug "Unable to detect application ABI's"

Tags: android, android-ndk

When trying to debug android NDK code in eclipse I get this error:

```
[2014-08-20 11:33:26 - HelloJni] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2014-08-20 11:33:26 - HelloJni] 
[2014-08-20 11:33:26 - HelloJni] Unable to detect application ABI's
```

There are 3 other people who also work on the same code but don't have this issue (it only happens on my computer).

Eclipse Luna 4.4.0
Android NDK r10, the Windows 32-bit package
ADT plugin version 23.0.3

I have tried deleting eclipse and reinstalling it along with CDT and the ADT plugin. I've also tried to debug the HelloJni sample from the ndk with the same error.

When I run "ndk-build DUMP_APP_ABI" I get this:

```
D:\Android\android-ndk\samples\hello-jni>ndk-build DUMP_APP_ABI
all

D:\Android\android-ndk\samples\hello-jni>
```

Is there anything else known that could cause this problem?

**EDIT**

my Application.mk looks like this

```
APP_ABI := all
APP_PLATFORM := android-14
```

Comment: Make sure you are running with adb as root (run "adb root" from desktop)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to detect application ABI's when trying to debug NDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12733125/unable-to-detect-application-abis-when-trying-to-debug-ndk)

Answer (score 1):

Add APP_PLATFORM to your android.mk file. Also make sure you have set your NDK path correctly on Preferences->Android->NDK.

Answer (score 0):

open the Application.mk and set APP_PLATFORM to the appropriate value e.g.:

```
APP_PLATFORM := android-11
```

This usually does it for me

In some cases you might also need to explicitly set the APP_ABI var, e.g.:

```
APP_ABI=armeabi
```

Comment: I both APP_ABI := all and APP_PLATFORM := android-14 in my Application.mk, same problem.